# ActionController::ParameterMissing in TrainingSessionsController#create + Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to implement a search function on my index page.  Following a tutorial I found online https://medium.com/@zylberberg.jonathan/creating-a-search-form-in-rails-5-77fdef6be74d

I plan to implement a more robust search but can't even get it to work for a single field yet, can't get past this error:param is missing or the value is empty: training_session.  Why does it call my create action at all?  I'm trying to call index which should correspond to training_sessions_path I think?

Additional error details:
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VG+v...==", "exercise_id"=>"1", "method"=>"get"}

Any help is appreciated, I must be making some fundamental mistake here somewhere. Pasted relevant code below

Index Page:

```
<%= form_tag(training_sessions_path method: :get) do%>
  Exercise <%= text_field_tag :exercise_id, params[:exercise_id]%>
<%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

TrainingSessionsController

```
def index
  if params[:exercise_id]
    @training_sessions = TrainingSession.joins(:exercise).where('exercise_id =', "%#{params[:exercise_id]}%")
  else
      @training_sessions = TrainingSession.joins(:exercise).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
  end
  end
  private
  def training_session_params
    params.require(:training_session).permit(:user_id, :exercise_id, :sets, :reps, :weight, :rpe, :training_date, :projected_max, :name)
  end
```

Routes:

```
training_sessions GET    /training_sessions(.:format)                                             training_sessions#index
                                     POST   /training_sessions(.:format)                                             training_sessions#create
                new_training_session GET    /training_sessions/new(.:format)                                         training_sessions#new
               edit_training_session GET    /training_sessions/:id/edit(.:format)                                    training_sessions#edit
                    training_session GET    /training_sessions/:id(.:format)                                         training_sessions#show
                                     PATCH  /training_sessions/:id(.:format)                                         training_sessions#update
                                     PUT    /training_sessions/:id(.:format)                                         training_sessions#update
                                     DELETE /training_sessions/:id(.:format)                                         training_sessions#destroy
training_sessions_calc_projected_max POST   /training_sessions/calc_projected_max(.:format)                          training_sessions#calc_projected_max
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your `routes.rb` but I can guess: in your form, if you are using the `training_sessions_path` then you will also need to provide the relevant training session model instance, or the training session id: e.g. `training_sessions_path(@training_session_object_please_create)` then it should work

Comment: Thanks it looks like it was a problem in my form pointed out below - appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `,` between path and method

```
<%= form_tag training_sessions_path, method: :get do%>
  Exercise <%= text_field_tag :exercise_id, params[:exercise_id]%>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you!  that got me past the error.  I knew it had to be something simple I was missing.

Comment: @mcannon can you show results on your console by running `rake routes | grep training_sessions`?